# Where do the intake/outtake tubes go on a motorcycle coolant reservoir?

Tags: motorcycle, coolant-reservoir

I do label things but this one got away from me. I feel extra stupid because it's just the in/out from the radiator reservoir but it's shut the whole operation down. I don't want to put the exhaust or fuel tank back on until I can find out where to plug these tubes into.

[diagram](https://www.google.com/search?q=39062-1107&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwia6NTYxO_OAhVPxWMKHat0ArwQ_AUICigD&biw=1618&bih=957#imgrc=IX5F56u59FY6dM%3A)

It's a low quality diagram because 39062 and 39062E are chopped in half in the diagram but in reality they're just rubber tubes.

I found **ONE** spot to plug in a tube from the radiator. Located:

```
radiator -> water pump -> engine -> thermostat housing -> radiator fill cap [TUBE GOES HERE] -> radiator
```

and I plugged the tube that is on top of the radiator into that because I figure if the thermostat lets more coolant into the radiator than the radiator has room for it will have to overflow into the coolant reservoir.  I'm pretty sure that's right.

But then I go looking for where to plug the tube that attaches to the bottom of the reservoir into and there are no places the tube fits.

I have taken this bike apart before and I don't remember those lines not fitting. So I'm surprised that I'm having such a hard time finding where to plug the bottom one in.

Comment: What is the make/model/year of the bike?

Comment: kawasaki 454 ltd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You plug the tube from the radiator into the coolant reservoir**

There are two plugs on the coolant reservoir

- Intake
- Vent

Typically, the intake will fill from the bottom of the reservoir and the vent will vent from the top or just near the plastic lid you can open.

**Brief Explanation**

The intake plug from the radiator needs to sit at the bottom in order to draw fluid.  If there is air in your cooling system it will expand dramatically under high heat conditions and will eventually get to the highest point in your cooling system, which is wear the radiator cap is on your radiator.  The expanded air will push the spring loaded seal of the radiator cap up allowing for high pressure steam and water to exit the system into the reservoir.

**Conclusion**

Use the hose to connect the radiator to the plug on the reservoir that is lower.

Use a second hose to connect to the highest vent hole and use this as a vent.  It will route down to exit at the bottom of the motorcycle.  The hose may even be routed from your disassembly within the fairing.

**Diagram Explanation**

49085 has a label within the box.  B with a circle around it.

On the hose labeled 92037 it has a B with a circle around it.

These are your connection points.  The lower nipple of the reservoir to the radiator.  The upper nipple as an atmospheric vent.

[image]